# Swift 4.1 JWT http header bearer returns 401 in server

Tags: ios, swift, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

When I tried to get a request from the server using the this http authorization header in swift 4.1 with this line of code:

`urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept")
urlRequest.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")`

But no luck, I received a `401 Unauthorized` response and printed the header in response and result is `Www-Authentication: Bearer error="invalid_token"`.

I tried using the token generated when I logged in with `SwaggerUI` in `Authorize` section and the result is correct and token is verified and accepted.

I don't know for sure what causes this error but I have big doubt that it has something to do with the `URLRequest`.

Is anyone also encountered the same issue as I am and has a solution on this one?

Comment: I had no trouble with `URLRequest` in general even with JWT. Usually there is some silly mistake like some header missing. Looking at one of my examples there is "Bearer" with JWT. Is is possible that is the issue?

Comment: if your `token` variable optional ? If so, the value will be `Optional(YOUR_TOKEN)`. I suggest you to download Charles Proxy and compare the request from Swagger and from the app

Comment: Hi @CZ54, yes indeed you have a very great point about that! What I did is I add `!` on the token variable and it solves the issue!  Thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: @AlvinQuezon you shouldn't do `!` to avoid the issue. Better use of the `guard let`  pattern and properly handle the `nil` case

Comment: Yeah, will do that right now, thanks for the great tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution! I hope I helped everyone with this solution, what I did is just make the token not optional so instead of `token` adding `!` helped me solve this issue!

> Credit for @CZ54 using the `guard` function instead of `!`

`guard let token = token else { return }
urlRequest.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")`